# JQUERY, CSS, When moused over an LI show a SPAN tag inside?

Tags: jquery, css

Given the following:

```
ul li .main .meta {opacity:0;}

<ul>
<li>  <span class="main">TITLE</span> <span class="meta">meta</span>  </li>
<li>  <span class="main">TITLE 2 </span> <span class="meta">meta</span>  </li>
<li>  <span class="main">TITLE 3</span> <span class="meta">meta</span>  </li>
etc... long list...
</ul>
```

What kind of JQUERY magic can I do so that whenever a user mouses over AnyWhere in the LI, the SPAN with the class=META, changes to Opacity:1, and when the user moves their mouse off that LI that LI's meta goes back to Opacity:0, and the new LI's meta goes to Opacity 1. etc....

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. The simplest implementation is:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").stop().fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

which will sort of work. The problem is that spans are inline elements and [`fadeIn()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) will change it to a block-level element.

**Note:** putting [`stop()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop) in there is a good habit to get into otherwise you can get unintended effects if you quickly fire off several animations on the same target.

You can do this with classes too:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").removeClass("hidden");
}, function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").addClass("hidden");
});
```

with:

```
span.hidden { display: none; }
```

but you lose the fade in and fade out effects this way. It does solve the `display: block` problem however.

You could alternatively [`animate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) the `opacity` but `opacity` isn't really supported on IE. See [opacity](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html):

> **IE compatibility note**
>
> If you want opacity to work in all IE
>   versions, the order should be:
>
> ```
> .opaque {
>   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
>   filter: alpha(opacity=50);                    // second!
> }
> ```
>
> If you don’t use this order,
>   IE8-as-IE7 doesn’t apply the opacity,
>   although IE8 and a pure IE7 do.

This code looks something like this:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").stop().animate({opacity: 0.0});
}, function() {
  $(this).find("span.meta").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0});
});
```

One question you have to answer is: do you want the "meta" content to not be rendered or just not be visible? There's a difference. To not be rendered is like `display: none`. To not be visible is like `opacity: 0` which could potentially confuse the user since the text will still be selectable.

IMHO I think you'd be better off accepting the block nature of the display or to use a tooltip (even a rich tooltip) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('li').hover(
    function() { $('span.meta', this).show(); },
    function() { $('span.meta', this).hide(); }
});
```

By the way, the correct way to hide an element in CSS is to use either `visibility: hidden` (if you want it to occupy space) or `display:none` (if you don't want it to occupy space)

Comment: missing a comma between the functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li.main').mouseover(function(evt){ $(this).find('span.meta').show(); });
```

I think...

Comment: Agreed. As the other answers show, its pretty easy to handle the mouse out event.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation is the purely CSS one;

```
ul li .meta {opacity:0;}
ul li:hover .meta {opacity:1;}
```

It won't do any fade in/out effects but it achieves your goal. Using display or visibility, depending on whether or not you want the text to affect page layout when not visible, may be desirable to opacity from a browser support standpoint.

Comment: CSS Transitions could be used for the animation effect on WebKit at least